# Parse dummy variable table to correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
df:
     A   B   C   D
#1   1   0   1   1
#2   0   0   1   1
#3   0   1   0   1
```

That can be read as: the #1 event is observed in A, C, and D, #2 is observed in C, #3 is observed in B, D
Now I want to parse this data to correlation matrix between A, B, C, D as:

```
    A   B   C   D
A   1   0   1   1
B   0   1   0   1
C   1   0   2   2
D   1   1   2   3
```

That can be read as: there is 0 event occurred in both A and B, there is 1 event occur in both A and C, and so on.

I can do it with this strategy:

```
# input is df
correltation_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.nan([4,4])
correltation_matrix[0, :] = df[['B', 'C', 'D']]*df['A'].sum()
```

and then loop for the whole dataframe, but if the number of variables is high, it seems to be non-efficient. How can I improve my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the matrix dot product to achieve that.

```
correltation_matrix = (df.T).dot(df)
```

Where `(df.T)` is `df` transposed.

Comment: just found out that `df.T @ df` also works for python >= 3.5

Answer (score 1):

To complement @ferhen's answer, I would add that you can significantly outperform `np.dot` with properly configured Tensorflow. For `df.shape == (1000, 2000)`, I get the following timings (on a free tier of Google Colab).

```
tf.linalg.tensordot(df.T, df, axes=1) # 3.12 seconds
np.dot(df.T, df)                      # 49.9 seconds
```

Comment: yah, nice catch, tensorflow works best with matrix operator. I just didn't remember that the correlation matrix is actually the dot product of the original table and its transpose matrix, silly me

Comment: Correlation is a word that gets a lot of abuse, so don't feel bad ;) Pandas does implement correlation coefficient through `pd.DataFrame.corr` for several correlation measures, but neither matches your definition.